# Passing an Array to a method, Encountering Error is "cannot find symbol songArray"

Tags: java

I am attempting to pass an array to a method. I keep getting an error while compiling, the error is "cannot find symbol songArray".

**SongTestDrive**

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class SongTestDrive {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] Song = { "Song title: soul to squeeze", "Artist: Red Hot Chili Peppers", "Genre: Funk Rock", "Year: 1993", "Song title: Slaughtered",
                "Artist: PanterA", "Genre: Groove Metal", "Year: 1994" };

        songArray(); //<--- Im having issues right here//
    }
}
```

**Song**

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Song {
    String name;
    String artist;
    String genre;
    int year;

    public void songArray(String[] Song) {
        for (String o : Song) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, o);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You need a instance object to call other class methods.

do like this

```
new Song().songArray(Song);
```

or

```
Song s = new Song()
s.songArray(Song);
```

Better practice you try to maintain java naming conventions.

eg

> Change String[] songs ={}; to String[] Song ={}; and make call like below

```
new Song().songArray(songs);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
songArray(); //<--- Im having issues right here//
```

this isn't a static method, it is instance method of class `Song`, you need `Song` instance to call that method

like

```
new Song().songArray(Song);
```

---

**See**

- [Understanding Instance and Class Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an instance of `Song` to call a method of that class. Also, you need to pass the array as the method `songArray()` takes a `String array` but you've not provided any parameter in the method call.

```
new Song().songArray(Song);
// new Song() creates a Song instance
// songArray(song) calls the songArray method of Song class and passes the Song array to it.
```

Answer (score 0):

The method

```
songArray(); //<--- Im having issues right here//
```

does not exist.

Also the class Song has not been created so first you will need

```
Song songClass = new Song ();
songClass.songArray(Song); //<--- No issues right here//
```

Comment: Thank You to all, I really appreciate what this forum has to offer, and I am excited to eventually be able to help others here as I have been helped!

Answer (score 0):

try this::

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class SongTestDrive
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] songs ={"Song title: soul to squeeze","Artist: Red Hot Chili Peppers","Genre: Funk Rock","Year: 1993","Song title: Slaughtered","Artist: PanterA","Genre: Groove Metal","Year: 1994"};
        Song song =  new Song(); // create object of song class, then use that object to call methods of Song class
        song.songArray(songs); //<---there won't be any issue now// 
        // by doing songArray(), compiler thought that songArray() is part of SongTestDrive class hence the 'cannot find symbol songArray' exception
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You very much, I appreciate you taking the time to not only show me where my code was broken, but explain why it was!

Comment: you are welcome. Please accept the answer that you feel solved your problem so that other people will get an idea that issue is resolved.